# Manipulating JSX element's children collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have a React JSX element and I want to iterate through it's children, perform replace (or any other operation) on each string element within it, and return new, modified JSX element. For example:

```
var element = <span>Text { var1 } Text2 text3 { var2 }</span>;
var modifiedChildren = [];
element.props.children.forEach(function(child){
    if(typeof child === 'string') {
        var modifiedChild = child.replace('a', 'b');
        modifiedChildren.push(modifiedChild);
    }
}
var modifiedElement = element;
modifiedElement.props.children = modifiedChildren;
```

However, `element.props.children` is read-only, which prevents me from doing this. But that's not what I want either, I just want to make new JSX element with modified children.

What could be the way to achieve this while remaining in ReactJS way of thinking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `React.Children.Map` for iterating over the children of a component.

```
React.Children.map(children, function[(thisArg)])
```

Some thing like this:

```
renderChildren() {
  return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
    React.cloneElement(child, {
      newProp: this.props.name
    })
  })
}
```

To immutably change the element you can use, `React.cloneElement`

```
React.cloneElement(
  element,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Check this [link](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/#changing-children-props) for more information